# How to open a specific Album directly in Photos of iPhone using objective c

Tags: ios

How to open a specific Album in Photos of iPhone using objective c,for example you have an album name trip so i want to go directly into it

Comment: Are you using UIImagePicker ?

Comment: Yes,I'm using UIImagePicker @Rajatp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that with `UIImagePickerController`. This is the limitation of Using the Default Controllers.

If you want to do it then you have to do it Photos Framework and you have to create your own Custom Image Picker.

Comment: Any tutorials to help us achieve this?

Comment: iOS11 now allows for this using SmartAlbums